# How to create a connector for Beanstalkd message queue in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-7, connector, beanstalkd

I have Beanstalkd message queue and I have Glassfish. Currenly I have created custom connection pool and connection management but it does not work properly. Connections left there and it's not managed by the container (GF4.0).
How to create a proper connector for Glassfish that would be managed by Glassfish? Any hint or link is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I developed BeanstalkdConnector JCA connector. It's freely available at GitHub: https://github.com/svenvarkel/beanstalkdconnector